# protobuf UnsupportedOperationException ensureIsMutable on insertion to list

Tags: protobuf-java

I'm working with protobuf and trying to insert to:

`builder.addAllConversions(new ArrayList(campaignOptimization.getConversions()));`

Where conversions is defined as `repeated int32 conversions = 5;`
and the original campaignOptimization.getConversions() is a Kotlin list of Ints

Getting UnsupportedOperationException ensureIsMutable

Answer (score 1):

I was injecting that builder (.newBuilder) from outside that class, and doing all sorts of:

```
if (that != null) {
  builder.setThat(that);
}
```

when finally I got to the code above, it threw that exception.

so I tried creating a new MyObj.newBuilder(builder.build()).addAllConversions(..)

and that worked!
Not sure why though..

Fresh newBuilder does not have issues with the mutability status of its collections